# Melt and cast data table using pattern

Tags: r, data.table

The `data.table` package added a new feature to `melt` data into multiple columns simultaneously. This is very useful, but I can't figure out how to preserve the "suffix" of the pre-melted variable names. For example:

```
library(data.table)

# create data table
dt <- data.table(id = seq(3), a_3 = seq(3), a_4 = seq(4, 6), b_3 = seq(7, 9), b_4 = seq(10, 12))

# melt and cast in one step using new feature
m1 <- melt(dt, id.vars='id', measure=patterns("a_", "b_"), value.name=c("a_", "b_"))
```

Results in the data table:

```
   id variable a_ b_
1:  1        1  1  7
2:  2        1  2  8
3:  3        1  3  9
4:  1        2  4 10
5:  2        2  5 11
6:  3        2  6 12
```

This is the  "shape" I want, but the variables `a_3`, `a_4`, `b_3` and `b_4` have been indexed `1` and `2`.  What I want is the `variable` column to contain `3,3,3,4,4,4`, according to the suffixes of the variable names.

I could obviously do this the "old-fashioned" way with `melt`, `strsplit`, `dcast`, but that's kind of cumbersome. I'm hoping for a one-line solution that's still very fast.

Comment: Agree this is important to have. Unfortunately doesn't seem to be implemented yet: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with `splitstackshape`.  It gives the '.time_1' column automatically

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(dt, var.stubs=c("a", "b"), sep="_")
#   id .time_1 a  b
#1:  1       3 1  7
#2:  1       4 4 10
#3:  2       3 2  8
#4:  2       4 5 11
#5:  3       3 3  9
#6:  3       4 6 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
> m1[ , variable:= c(3,4)[variable] ]
> m1
   id variable a_ b_
1:  1        3  1  7
2:  2        3  2  8
3:  3        3  3  9
4:  1        4  4 10
5:  2        4  5 11
6:  3        4  6 12
```

Comment: That works. I was avoiding something like that because in my real situation I have thousands of variables and don't want to list out what all their suffixes are. I suppose I could use `gsub` on the list of variable names to isolate all of the suffixes, but then it's getting pretty close to the amount of effort in the `melt`, `strsplit`, `dcast` approach...

Comment: The `c(3,4)` could be replaced with `sub("^a_", "",  names(dt)[grepl("^a_", names(dt))])`, possibly needing to be sorted if they are not naturally that way.

Comment: Thanks. This is kind of the convoluted thing I was trying to avoid. My variable suffixes are character strings that aren't necessarily sorted, and there are many of them. I was hoping there would be a "natural" way to use this feature of `melt.data.table`, but I can take a hint that there isn't. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I think you only need to do it for one variable, otherwise the rearrangement doesn't make sense.